# Space before semicolons (French) in natbib citations

Tags: natbib, french

In French, you can find a space before and after a semicolon. How can I add a space before the semicolon in multiple citation calls-out?

I specify that I am using the `french` version of the `babel` package and the `authordate3` bibliographic style.

Here is what I have:

> (Author1 2000; Author2 2001)

and what I would like:

> (Author1 2000 ; Author2 2001)

Comment: In a short example I just tried (https://gist.github.com/moewew/fe3c965c2e2070d0df3f12e4ab842d7d) the space could automatically be added with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, but not with pdfLaTeX. (I may very well have missed something.) You could try to force the space manually with `\setcitestyle{citesep={\,;}}`.

Comment: @moewe \setcitestyle{citesep={ ;}} works just fine. Thank you!